# Tensorflow: reduce_prod gradient broken?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, shapes

I'm trying to minimize a simple loss defined over a variable tensor with size `n*m`
The problem is when I'm running optimization, I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape () must have rank 1
```

The curious thing is that if instead of `tf.reduce_prod` I use `tf.reduce_sum`, it works just fine, yet the shape of the loss remains the same. 
Can anyone try this and tell me if the result is the same elsewhere?

```
def someloss(a):
    da=tf.reduce_prod(a,reduction_indices=1)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.square(da)))

n=5 
m=2
a=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n,m],mean=1.0, stddev=0.35))
cost=someloss(a)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(100):
        sess.run(opt)
```

Comment: can't reproduce...

Comment: Does it work for you? you have no error?

Comment: Yes, it works for me.

Comment: Ok, i'm using an old version of tensorflow...
Thanks!

edit: My version was old, the problem has been fixed for a few months https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2641

Answer (score 0):

OP self-solved the problem:  This was an [old TensorFlow bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2641) that has been fixed long before the 1.0 release and should no longer be relevant to others.